# Multiple networks - React Native picks wrong ip when Virtualbox/Vmware installed

Tags: android, node.js, windows, networking, virtualbox

I'm working with windows 10, connected to my home Wifi. I have installed VMWare & Virtualbox as well.

When I try to run react native app, with `npm start`, it picks the wrong ip which is infarct virtualbox ip. It's not picking the ip of my wireless network. How can I make it use the correct IP, so I can access it from my phone ( which is on the same network as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution. The following steps helped me.

1. First I connected my laptop with wifi.
2. Click Run in Start Menu and type ncpa.cpl to open Network Connections. Or open Control Panel and search for 'network connections'
3. Right-Click on 'Wifi' > select 'Properties' > 'Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)' [don't uncheck the mark]
4. Go to "Properties" > "Advanced..." > (Uncheck 'Automatic Metric') > Type in the text-box below that (Interface Metric) : 10.
5. Click OK and OK and OK :)
6. Then do the same for the other "Virtual Box-xxxxx" networks. But instead put 20 in the Interface Metric text-box.
7. Click OK, OK and OK.
8. Try restarting your app on Expo. It must work now!

[Source](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60)